# Baby Rudin 6.1, Proof verification

Tags: proof-verification, definite-integrals

Could anyone give me guidance with the proof of the following problem?

> Suppose $\alpha$ increases in $[a,b]$, $\alpha$ is coutinuous at $x_0$, $f(x_0)=1$, and $f(x_0)=0$ if $x\neq x_0$. Prove that $f$ belongs to a set of Reimann Stieltjes functions and that $\int f d\alpha=0$ .

In the proof of Roger Cooke(https://minds.wisconsin.edu/bitstream/handle/1793/67009/rudin%20ch%206.pdf?sequence=6&isAllowed=y), he proves it by showing that

> $\sum_{k=0}^{n}f(t_j)(\alpha(t_k)-\alpha(t_{k-1}))$

will be lower that any finite $\epsilon$.

I don't understand why this should prove it.

Since from definition, for a function to have a Riemann Stieltjes integral, the upper and lower Reimann integrals of $f$ should be equal.

But in the proof, it is only proved that the difference is small than any finite number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a non-negative number is smaller than any finite number, it must be zero (you can try to prove it). Rudin actually has a theorem (Theorem 6.6) which says that the necessary and sufficient condition to show that a function is Riemann Integrable is by showing that the difference of the upper and lower integral are smaller than any finite number.

Comment: Thank you so much!!